# Azure ad B2C custom policy with external IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have created a custom policy in azure AD B2C which uses an external login provider (open id connect).

Everything seems to work fine in terms of the registered application using B2C to login.

However the user is not saved in B2C. These are my orchestrationsteps:

```
<OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ContosoExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ContosoExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MY_IDP" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims"
          CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
```

Is there something additional that I have to do to actually save the user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Have a look at the base policy.

You need to add all the steps using AlternativeSecurityId and to write, you use "AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId".

Note that this creates a "shadow" account, not a local user.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure but just from an observation, you have 3 steps in this user journey.

1. The first step presents the user to select an IdP to login.
2. The second references your "MY_IDP" technical profile, which is probably
   where you're performing actions to get user claims/logging the user in?
3. The third is outputting the claims.

That said, you need an additional step(s), specifically between steps 2 (when you get claims for a user) and step 3 (sending the token back). Once you "login" the user and get user claims back, you need to save it.

Under the hood, an Azure B2C tenant is using an active directory/entra ID instance. So you need another technical profile that connects to AAD (for your B2C tenant) to save the users. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#protocol) and look at the `AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId` and `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail`. Notice you are performing write operations.

Also, not sure about your use case but you'll probably also want an addition step before saving the user to make sure the user doesn't exist. If the user does already exist, skip over saving that user. If you want this, you'll want another technical profile that performs an AAD read, like `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId` and `AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError`